# error: no matching function for call to...(std::string&)

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following compiler error

> error: no matching function for call to 'infxTree(std::string&)'

For this bit of code.

```
int main(){
string infxStr;

cout << "Enter an infix string: " << endl;
cin >> infxStr;


prefixOutput(infxTree(infxStr));
postorderOutput(infxTree(infxStr), ' ');
displayTree(infxTree(infxStr), infxStr.size());
    return 0;
```

}

I get the error on all the last 3 lines.  Here's the function:

```
template <typename T>
tnode<T> infxTree(const string& iexp);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the template parameter explicitly:

```
infxTree<Foo>(infxStr)
```

Where `Foo` is the class type provided to your templated `tnode` class.

Comment: Thanks!  The program still doesn't work,  but at least now it compiles so I can try to figure out why!  Much obliged.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no clue in the function signature as to what T is, you have to specify it explicitly as a template type parameter.

```
inxTree<int>(infxStr);
```

This can be omitted if you have any arguments that depend on T, that the compiler can use to infer the type:

```
node<T> inxTree(string str, T item) { /* ... */ }
int item;
inxTree(infxStr, item); // OK
```